# Get truth value of column value in sqlite query

Tags: sqlite, truthiness

If I have a column in a table of zero and nonzero numbers, how do I get the {0,1} truth value of it?

Data

```
x, y
0, 111
1, 0
2, 444
```

(sql query, something like `select x, TRUTHOF(y) from Data`)

Result

```
x, y_truth
0, 1
1, 0
2, 1
```

Using sqlite3 in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite, boolean expressions return 0 or 1, so you can just compare against zero:

```
SELECT x, y != 0 AS y_truth FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Er, what about:

```
SELECT x, not not y FROM Data
```

I'm not sure I understand the question, though...